# Software installed from .deb files won't launch

Tags: software-installation, deb, anydesk

Linux newbie here!

I freshly installed the latest Ubuntu 22.04 version on my PC and I'm having trouble with .deb files.

While I can install them without issues, when I run the program it just won't start. Nothing happens.

This is the case for several programs I tried: AnyDesk, Parsec and Zoom.

Is there any reason why it wouldn't work?

I also tried sudo apt-get -f update in order to update dependencies, but nothing was found.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: If you are new to Ubuntu and Linux I would caution you against installing software from `.deb` files. In many cases the package you will find/choose will not be compatible with your version of Ubuntu and if you do this often you can quickly run into dependency problems. I would only use a `.deb` file as a last resort. For example, zoom is available as a snap, so you probably should use that.

Comment: In order to understand the problems we will need the full texts of the errors you are getting as well as the steps/commands you use to reproduce the problem. Copy/paste this info into your question and use [code fences](https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code) to preserve formatting

Comment: There's a very good chance that this is a Wayland problem. Log into a X11/Xorg session and see if these apps launch. If they don't, open them in the terminal, and copy the errors, and paste them into your question. Report back. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: Most likely each software has a different fix, but without the error logs that's hard to ascertain. Usually an easy way to find such logs is by running the installed application in the Terminal, for exemple type anydesk and it will try and launch it, any errors will then be printed and you can provide them here. Additionally, as a shot in the dark, I had a problem with installing the anydesk deb in 22.04 and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1405323/anydesk-doesn-t-work-after-upgrading-to-ubuntu-22-04-lts/1405354#1405354) is how I got it solved.

Answer (score 3):

> EDIT

I have an answer.
Install

```
cd /tmp 
curl -O http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openssl/libssl1.1_1.1.1l-1ubuntu1.3_amd64.deb
dpkg -i libssl1.1_1.1.1l-1ubuntu1.3_amd64.deb
```

and it runs.

> END Edit

I can't comment on the running thread because of my "Reputation"... But I have the same issue. Parsec was running fine on an upgrade system to 22.04. Performances were terrible and after messing with the drivers decided to just reinstall a fresh ubuntu 22.04.

Parsec comes only as a .deb, pretty straightforward to install. But yes, running the app after a fresh install of 22.04 does pretty much nothing. No log, no error message. Wait 1 second and nothing.
There are a few files created in the user home folder .parsec

Running on xorg or wayland has not effect.

That's what we get:

```
flo@flo-defiant:~$ parsecd
flo@flo-defiant:~$
```

Might see if I can reach someone on the discord too.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem with Parsec on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, that helped me

link to Parsec's lib requirement:
https://support.parsec.app/hc/en-us/articles/115003477771-Using-Parsec-With-other-Linux-Distros (obsolet Link)

UPDATE: (2024.01)

--

link to Parsec's lib requirement:
https://support.parsec.app/hc/en-us/articles/4422939258893#other_distros

--

```
sudo apt install libnx-x11-6 libffi7 libasound2 libxcursor-dev libgl-dev libudev1
```

You could auto confirm by typing " -y" behind the last lib (for libudev1 -y)
otherwise confirm with yes to download and install those libs.

just like "user2068020" said, try to get "libssl"

```
cd /tmp 
curl -O http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openssl/libssl1.1_1.1.1l-1ubuntu1.3_amd64.deb
sudo apt install ./libssl1.1_1.1.1l-1ubuntu1.3_amd64.deb
```

UPDATE: (2022.08)

--

```
cd /tmp 
curl -O http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openssl/libssl1.1_1.1.1-1ubuntu2.1~18.04.20_amd64.deb
sudo apt install ./libssl1.1_1.1.1-1ubuntu2.1~18.04.20_amd64.deb
```

link to packages: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openssl/

--

with "apt install ..." instead of "dpkg -i ..." it automatically loads missing packages.

If you try typing "anydesk" to your console, you might get more information about missing libs or errors.

```
user@Ubuntu2204:~$ anydesk
```