# AnyDesk doesn’t work after upgrading to Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Tags: upgrade, deb, 22.04, anydesk

After upgrading to `Ubuntu 22.04 LTS`, when I open AnyDesk app (downloaded from official website `.deb` file) nothing happens. In logs I can see this error/message:

```
Could not create transient scope for PID 7866: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnixProcessIdUnknown: Process with ID 7866 does not exist.
```

```
/usr/bin/anydesk: error while loading shared libraries: libpangox-1.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Any idea, how to resolve this?

Answer (score 53):

I followed [this guide](https://web.archive.org/web/20221206142133/https://www.how2shout.com/linux/install-anydesk-on-ubuntu-22-04-lts-jammy-via-command-terminal/) and got it to work.

Essentially, you need to download and install `libpangox` manually with:

```sh
wget http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/p/pangox-compat/libpangox-1.0-0_0.0.2-5.1_amd64.deb
```

Then run the following command:

```sh
sudo apt install ./libpangox-1.0-0_0.0.2-5.1_amd64.deb
```

Comment: I used dpkg -i ./libpangox-1.0-0_0.0.2-5.1_amd64.deb works like a charm

Comment: It's work for me.Thanks a lot!

Comment: Its works for me after migration to 22.04 version

Comment: It worked..thanks

Comment: on arm64 version this solution don't work