# AnyDesk keeps changing id after reboot on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Tags: 22.04, remote-desktop, reset, anydesk

After upgrading a system to Ubuntu 22.04 LTS I can't automatically connect to the station via AnyDesk because it keeps changing id on each reboot. Manual connection works fine and it allows unattended connection as well but only until reboot. Then it will assign a new id and default settings.

I tried looking into `~/.anydesk/` or `/etc/anydesk/` as pointed in the [manual](https://support.anydesk.com/knowledge/anydesk-id-and-alias) but it has no effect, first time new id is generated it will be saved on disk, but after reboot new id will be saved only somewhere in memory.

I've also tried [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1405323/anydesk-doesn-t-work-after-upgrading-to-ubuntu-22-04-lts) and installing older versions without any success.

My current workaround is just to login via chrome remote desktop after reboot and restart anydesk manually. Here is [guide](https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/wrp4dr/ubuntu_2204_and_chrome_remote_desktop_trouble/) on how to set it up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to solve this problem for me. The reason id kept changing was because of anydesk's service that was starting before desktop loads. So to fix this I tried removing anydesk service competely and to make it start automatically I added anydesk to startup applications via ubuntu's gui tool. So that it starts only after desktop.

Unfortunately I did all of this long ago and never recorded exact steps, everything is just working since. So please excuse me not providing commands and screenshots.