# Parsec login not working - Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: deb, debian, remote, 22.04

When I try to click the [login button on Parsec](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Xkmu.png) NOTHING happens, fresh install of Ubuntu 22.04 LTS.

I saw a similar post when I did a [Google search for this problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1GUYC.png) however, this post has been removed :/

Comment: There are helpful answers to this question in [another AskUbuntu discussion](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1403873/software-installed-from-deb-files-wont-launch).

Answer (score -1):

I am also facing the same issue with Parsec.

Pretty sure they don't support 22.04 LTS yet because on their official site its written "Ubuntu 18.04 LTS Support Release"

However, they do have [this page](https://support.parsec.app/hc/en-us/articles/115003477771-Using-Parsec-With-other-Linux-Distros) for using Parsec with other Linux distros and the required packages needed to configure Parsec

You're probably better off not using Parsec since they don't support hosting for Linux, and If you really want to use It then just dual boot with Windows.

If anyone has any solutions for this please reply to the thread.

Comment: Thank you, at least I know there isn't anything I can really do about it on 22.04

Comment: Downvoted because "use Windows" is not a great answer for software that's supported on an earlier version of Ubuntu.

Comment: There are answers in this post: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1403873/software-installed-from-deb-files-wont-launch